# Inserir um caractere em um ponto especifico de uma String

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou precisando de uma luz. Tenho um programa que recebe, processa um txt e joga no banco.
O txt vem dessa forma:

1;;Nome Empresa 145241;00.000.000/0001-77;A;0,00000000;5000

Cada ' ; ' separa as informações que são passadas para o banco.

O problema é que eu preciso pegar só o código que está ao lado do Nome Empresa.

E não consigo pensar de alguma forma de inserir um ; ali separando a empresa do código sem inserir também entre o espaço que existe entre o Nome da empresa.

Comment: Sempre nesse formato?

Comment: O problema dessa pergunta é o formato. Se as informações vierem sempre nessa ordem o processamento é simples e pode ser feito em uma linha mas se ordem da informação varia precisará de algo um pouco mais elaborado.

Comment: Vem sempre nesse formato e ordem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código abaixo resolve o seu problema:

```
$string = 'Nome Empresa 145241';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}; $2';
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $out;
```

recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação da função [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)

Pode ser necessário alterar o regex da variavel `$pattern` para se encaixar no padrão da sua string

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui adaptar ao meu código. Grato demais pela ajuda !